# Android 4.4: How to get a list of all installed printers?

Tags: android, printing, android-4.4-kitkat, android-print-framework

How can I get the PrinterIds of all the installed printers using the Android 4.4 printing API? Those printers (only printer devices) that show up at the printing UI.
What I'd like to do is to iterate through all available printers and output there capabilities.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrinterDiscoverySession.html#onStartPrinterDiscovery(java.util.List<android.print.PrinterId>)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [PrinterDiscoverySession](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrinterDiscoverySession.html) class to get this information.